# how to prevent SWIG memory leak when applying global inner class workaround from SWIG manual section on Nested Classes?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, swig

I am applying the workaround from SWIG manual section on Nested Classes, that uses the global Inner class.  Here I will show you a version like in the manual, but simplified for you as much as possible.  I also had to add the inline definition `{}` to `method()` because without that SWIG would not work at all.

```
// File outer.h
class Outer {
public:
  class Inner {};
  void method() {}
};


// File : example.i

// Redefine nested class in global scope in order for SWIG to generate
// a proxy class. Only SWIG parses this definition.
class Inner {};

%{
#include "outer.h"
%}
%include "outer.h"

%{
// SWIG thinks that Inner is a global class, so we need to trick the C++
// compiler into understanding this so called global type.
typedef Outer::Inner Inner;
%}
```

This works well.  However, suppose I change `method()` to create and return the nested `Inner()`:

```
Inner method() { return Inner(); }
```

Now, the results are as I expect (in the real more complex example), so that is not my problem.  My problem is, this warns of a leak:  repeated application of

```
>>>Outer().method()
```

results in

```
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'Outer::Inner *', no destructor found.
```

I know how to fix this kind of thing - provide the full definition of the offending class to SWIG. However, the full definition of the global scope `Inner` class is already provided.  In fact, the definition of the nested class is provided as well but SWIG I guess ignores it and the warning continues.

So the nested class works for me as expected, except I get a memory leak warning.

How to avoid it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SWIG documentation ([6.27 Nested Classes](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_nested_classes)), it looks like there is a feature flag `%nestedworkaround` that can work around this exact issue:

```
%module x

class Inner {
};

%nestedworkaround Outer::Inner;

%inline %{
class Outer {
public:
  class Inner {};
  Inner method() { return Inner(); }
};
%}

%{
typedef Outer::Inner Inner;
%}
```

Result:

```
>>> import x
>>> x.Outer().method()
<x.Inner; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'Inner *' at 0x0000000002AE6880> >
>>> x.Outer().method()
<x.Inner; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'Inner *' at 0x0000000002AE69A0> >
```

Without that flag, I received a warning processing the SWIG interface:

```
x.i(15) : Warning 325: Nested class not currently supported (Inner ignored)
```

And this was the result:

```
>>> import x
>>> x.Outer().method()
<Swig Object of type 'Outer::Inner *' at 0x0000000002AA6880>
>>> x.Outer().method()
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'Outer::Inner *', no destructor found.
<Swig Object of type 'Outer::Inner *' at 0x0000000002AA69A0>
```